# Django: how do I include a url link in a form label

Tags: django, forms, url, reverse

My use case looks very basic but I couldn't find anything on the web!

The idea is a form with checkbox "I have read and agree to the terms and conditions"
And a link on "terms and conditions" which points to a page with such terms and conditions...
Classic!

So I have a field in my form as follows:

```
tos = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(),
                         label=_(u'I have read and agree to the <a href="%s" target="_blank">terms and conditions</a>' % reverse('terms_of_use')),
                         initial=False)
```

where 'terms of use' is the name of one of my url patterns in urls.py

But I get an error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf urls doesn't have any patterns in it
```

My urlconf works fine on the whole site so I supposed that the problem was that the urlconf is not yet populated when the form is rendered ?

I tried using lazy_reverse = lazy(reverse, str) instead of reverse, but it doesn't solve anything.

Is there a way to make this work ? The use case seems very very basic so there surely is a way to do it without having to break up the form inside my template ?!

Comment: Guess: `reverse` has a `current_app` kwarg, maybe it needs a little direction on which `urls.py` to load.

Comment: the error message is traced from: raise ImproperlyConfigured("The included urlconf %s doesn't have any patterns in it" % self.urlconf_name)        which indicates that he knows ?

Answer (score 3):

lazy_reverse won't work since you're turning around and unlazying it the second after with your `"...%s..." % lazy(blah)` notation.

I suppose you could try to lazy the whole thing, i.e.

```
label = lazy(lambda: _("bla %s bla" % reverse('something')))
```

but I did not test this

alternatively, just override the label at `__init__`, i.e.

```
self.fields['myfield'].label = 'blah %s bla' % reverse('bla')
```

Comment: Klaas, I tried many syntaxes around what you proposed but it printed something like: "at 0xa6b917c>".    So for the moment I have put it in __init__ where it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I use this syntax

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.functional import lazy

privacy = forms.BooleanField(label = lazy(lambda: _("Privacy <a href='%s' a>policy</a>" % reverse('privacy'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a link a form label like this:

```
foo_filter=forms.ModelChoiceField(FooFilter.objects.all(),
               label=format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', reverse_lazy('foo-filter'), 
                                 FooFilter._meta.verbose_name))
```

See [AppRegistryNotReady: lazy format_html()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602151/appregistrynotready-when-starting-unitest-via-pycharm/36602152#36602152)