# AppRegistryNotReady: lazy format_html()?

Tags: django

Why do I get this exception?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path1/myapp-isu/myapp_isu/tests/unit/views/test_view_isu.py", line 8, in <module>
    from myapp_isu.search_form import ISUSearchForm
  File "/path1/myapp-isu/myapp_isu/search_form.py", line 87, in <module>
    class ISUSearchForm(forms.Form):
  File "/path1/myapp-isu/myapp_isu/search_form.py", line 108, in ISUSearchForm
    foo_filter=forms.ModelChoiceField(FooFilter.objects.all(), label=format_html('<a href="%s">%s</a>', reverse_lazy('foo-filter'), FooFilter._meta.verbose_name))
  File "/path1/dt/dt/utils/templateutils.py", line 127, in reverse
    return urlresolvers.reverse(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path1/dt/dt/utils/urlresolverutils.py", line 49, in patched_reverse
    base_url = orig_reverse(viewname, urlconf=urlconf, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, prefix=prefix, current_app=current_app)
  File "/path2/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 578, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/path2/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 432, in _reverse_with_prefix
    self._populate()
  File "/path2/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 284, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/path2/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 401, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/path2/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/path1/myapp-eins/myapp_eins/etc/rooturls.py", line 13, in <module>
    admin.autodiscover()
  File "/path2/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/path2/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 67, in autodiscover_modules
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
  File "/path2/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/path2/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

It only happens if I call the unittest via PyCharm, not if I use py.test on the shell.

I guess `reverse_lazy()` is not lazy here, since it gets used in `format_html()`. Any way to have a lazy `format_html()`?

Versions:

- Django 1.8
- Pycharm 5.0.4

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect PyCharm might not be calling Django test runner properly. Django needs a bunch of things to happen for the tests to run properly, models need to be loaded, URL patterns parsed etc. For this reason Django uses a management command `manage.py test` to run tests. It is possible, that PyCharm is not aware of that.

Comment: Do you get the same exact error if you run the development server via PyCharm?

Comment: Also what PyCharm and Django versions are you using? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I added version info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are things like url_patterns in the stacktrace, I assume that `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set correctly .

But, you still need to call `django.setup()` before running anything else.

```
import django
django.setup()
```

For me, that made this error message go away.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some trouble using PyCharm, myself, and I'll assume you're using the the community edition (which I've been using).

If so, the problem is very likely that you're not properly configured for django. You can probably fix this with some hacks that might work for this.

I'd start off with [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840851/1842146)
(importing django to ensure the django console is run)

Then maybe [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28109123/1842146)

There's also this: 
Check "Edit Configurations" under the test you're running, and add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<app-name-here>.settings` to environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above fails, try initializing your form and doing the import in the constructor:

```
    class ISUSearchForm(...):

    ...

    foo_filter = forms.Field()

    ...

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs)

      from ... import reverse_lazy
      from ... import FooFilter

      self.fields['foo_filter'] = \
        forms.ModelChoiceField(
          FooFilter.objects.all(),
          label=format_html(
            '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
            reverse_lazy('foo-filter'),
            FooFilter._meta.verbose_name
          )
        )

      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The error may be caused by the exact `import` sequence performed by the different *test runners* and the fact that you use only *class variables* to customize your form.

Answer (score 0):

In django 1.8, reverse() and reverse_lazy() now return Unicode strings instead of byte strings.

Please refer the link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/